# How to efficiently transfer remotely millions of files

Tags: ssh, file-transfer, scp

In some machine there are almost five millions of small (50KB) text files. I need to send them to another machine on our LAN. I tried doing

```
scp *.txt remote_machine:
```

since ssh connection is setup passwordless between them. But a new connection is established for each file, so it is painstakingly slow.

I wonder therefore what would be the best strategy for doing this.

Comment: That command does not establish a connection for every file. It goes slow because of scp protocol internals: it is too talky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if scp is multi-threaded. If not try something like this so better utilize all cores/ cpus and network bandwidth:

```
scp [A-M]*.txt remote_machine:
scp [M-Z]*.txt remote_machine:
scp [0-9]*.txt remote_machine:
...
```

Of course the patterns to use depend on the naming of your files.

Instead of scp you could also use rsync with the same approach.

Comment: I think yours is the easiest, simplest and most effective approach from all the answers (also the others are very good options)

Answer (score 4):

You can make a `files.tar.gz` file before transferring.

Comment: it may pay off to use bzip2 or lzma also.

Comment: I have also found that bzip2 can run in parallel!

Comment: actually, you can run everything in parallel: `tar cf - $DIR | lzma -9 -c|ssh $HOST 'lzcat | tar xf -'`

Answer (score 1):

well ssh also means encyption/decryption, why not you use ftp rather to transfer ... if security is not a real concern ?

more over, you can archive the data and decompress it after transfering ... if your network is slow.

so in short, issue the following command to make archive ..

```
cd /path/to/transfer/folder
tar -cvpjf /tmp/transfer.tar.bz2 .
```

to tranfer you will issue command

```
ftp open remotemachine
put /tmp/transfer.tar.bz2
```

on reciving, you will issue command in the folder you wanted to issue all...

```
cd /path/where/to/extract
tar -xvpjf ~/transfer.tar.bz2
rm ~/transfer.tar.bz2
```

definately you can automate it, i automated this process for me to transfer big chunk of data to a target ...

Answer (score 1):

.tar.gz the files together and un.tar.gz the files apart at the other end.

```
tar cz *.txt | ssh remote_machine 'tar xz'
```

Ssh itself slows things down. If you are copying between hosts on the same network and security isn't an issue, it may be better to use a raw tcp connection.

```
remote_machine$ nc -l 3333 -q 1 | tar xz
local_machine$ tar cz *.txt >/dev/tcp/remote_machine/3333
```

If you want to use a different port number from 3333, make sure you change it in both lines.